# How to show OpenFileDialog in RoslynPad

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, .net-core-3.1, roslynpad

I using following code to show `OpenFileDialog` using [RoslynPad](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad), it complied and run, but no dialog appear, so the snippet keep running forever:

```cs
#r "framework:Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"

using System.Windows.Forms;

var fd = new OpenFileDialog
{
    Filter = "Solution files (*.sln)|*.sln"
};

if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    Console.WriteLine(fd.FileName);
```

What is correct way to make `OpenFileDialog` work with RoslynPad?

Environment:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit (2004)
- RoslynPad: built from lastest master branch.
- .NET Core: 3.1.402

Comment: A dialog always requires an owner window, one it can stay on top of.  There is [good evidence](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad/blob/master/src/RoslynPad.Avalonia/OpenFileDialogAdapter.cs) that is an unsubtle problem in this library.

Comment: @HansPassant I think a dialog don't need an owner window in order to work. Checked with this piece of code in Visual Studio (.Net Core 3.1 with `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` config in project): `static void Main() { var fd = new OpenFileDialog(); var result = fd.ShowDialog(); Console.WriteLine(result); }`.

Comment: The OpenFileDialog sometimes fails the first time you use the dialog.  The default folder in VS may not be set correctly.  I sometimes see this happen if you do not save project use File : SaveAll.  Other times you need to set default folder before you use ShowDialog.

Comment: @jdweng I'm able to make it work when run from Visual Studio. But in RoslynPad (a kind of lightweight editor), it doesn't work.

Comment: The code is using Windows Dialogs not WinForm.  See source at GitHub for Using Statement at top of module : https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad/blob/master/src/RoslynPad/FolderBrowserDialogAdapter.cs

Answer (score 1):

After checking the repo, I'm able to make `OpenFileDialog` work by adding below line:

```cs
await Helpers.RunWpfAsync();
```

The complete code is as below:

```cs
#r "framework:Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"

using Microsoft.Win32;

await Helpers.RunWpfAsync(); // initializes a dispatcher thread

var fd = new OpenFileDialog
{
    Filter = "Solution files (*.sln)|*.sln"
};

if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
    Console.WriteLine(fd.FileName);
```

`RunWpfAsync` creates a WPF `Dispatcher` thread and the code following the `await` runs under it. It will also work for Windows Forms.

Comment: @EliArbel thank you for providing an awesome open source project. It help me a lot!